# Why does truffle test break my migration process?

Tags: testing, solidity, smartcontracts, migrate, truffle

I have created a deployment script for an upgradable token contract which takes a flag from the command line for the deployment type.

I type...

```
truffle migrate --reset --type initial
truffle migrate --reset --type upgrade
truffle migrate --reset --type upgrade
```

if I type the commands in sequence, the upgrade succeeds every time for as many times as I need to.

But if any point after the initial deployment, I run...

```
truffle test --type initial
```

with or without following it with...

```
truffle test --type upgrade
```

it causes any further attempts to upgrade with...

```
truffle migrate --reset --type upgrade
```

to fail.

I thought the tests would be separated from my deployed contracts.

I asked chat GPT and it said to try adding the reset flag so I was able to do this...

```
truffle migrate --reset --type initial
truffle test --reset --type initial
truffle migrate --reset --type upgrade
truffle test --reset --type upgrade
```

but then when i run...

```
truffle migrate --reset --type upgrade
```

it fails, which suggests to me it was the test upgrade which caused it to fail

but I still don't know why